# Is there a way to make a navigation work inside a handler using Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create a splash screen using Jetpack Compose. I created my navigation and I have all my IDs to go to different screens, but I cannot make a screen navigate to another inside of a Hadler. How do you guys go about that?

```
    @Composable
fun GoToMainScreen(navController: NavHostController){
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(object : Thread() {
        override fun run() {
            navController.navigate("main_screen")
            Log.i("LOOPER", "It got here!")
        }
    }, 4000L)
}
```

Comment: You should never use a Handler to create a splash screen. That is bad behavior and not intended. What is the purpose of waiting for a damn splash screen? No user wants that.

Comment: is that an opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried this, and in my case it navigates fine with your composable:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "profile") {
    composable("profile") {
        GoToMainScreen(navController)
    }
    composable("main_screen") { Text("main_screen") }
}
```

Not sure what's different in your case, but in compose we wouldn't usually need `Handler`

First of all, you need to wrap creation of the handler `LaunchedEffect`, otherwise your handler may be created many times in case of screen recomposition.

And inside `LaunchedEffect` we can use coroutine, so same with much less code looks like:

```
@Composable
fun GoToMainScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        delay(2000L)
        navController.navigate("main_screen")
    }
}
```

If this still doesn't help make sure providing a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), something like my first block of code.

Comment: This works fine. Thanks a lot. I will mark it as best later.